# How do I generate monthly events?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a monthly event for every registered customer that fires an insert statement on billing table. If an event is specified to run from say **20th Aug 2013 0:00 hrs** (a future date), on what date can I expect next event to occur?

I don't know whether to assume it as 30 days or 365/12 days (mathematically).

I am using something like this to create that event:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH
STARTS '2013-08-20 00:00:00'
DO 
BEGIN

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

My question is when does mysql fire this event in the next month?

Comment: @Prix OK got it now. I was wondering why you made that edit earlier on. Because I thought the word 'I' shouldn't come in the question in forums like this. Anyways nice of you to explain.

Comment: @Prix A senior user like you may recommend to automate this feature as a feature request. Had you not told me, I wouldn't know right? And not only that, you have to take your time to explain.

Comment: Feel free to do so at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ there is probably a recommendation about it already regardless but its not like everything gets implemented as soon as it get requested and its not like I'm the only one doing it anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rescheduled events rely on the date interval function of MySQL. Your event would reoccur on:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2013-08-20', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

that's `2013-09-20`.

Fore more details about the date functions, see:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH... I don't want to reinvent it either. I just want to know when is the next date the event gets fired? Because some months have 30 days and others have 31 days. Hope I made it clear to you.

Comment: I am already employing the method you suggested. I just edited my question again to clarify things.

Comment: Understood that it fires the event at 00:00 hrs on 20th of every month  irrespective of the varying days difference between them. Yes it answers my question. +1

Comment: Yes, it does not shift the date at all. But using an interval of 30 or 31 DAY instead, would shift the reoccurence date each month to a different date since it depends on the days in each month.